# Set path to look for java.exe in the intellij codename plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, codenameone

I just install Codename plugin in Intellij and just about to start learning the tool. Have the following error message upon creating a new codename project in Intellij:

```
Error opening resource editor: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\bin"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\bin"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
```

The plugin should not look for java.exe inside android-sdk folder. I have set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the proper JDK path. This only happen in Codename plug-in.

Been searching SO for answer, but to no avail. Looking to tweak around the plugin way of finding java.exe.

OS: Windows 10, Intellij version: 2016.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the 3.3 or higher version of the plugin?

Notice that Android studio isn't a supported platform only IntelliJ IDEA itself.

I'd like to know more about how you were able to create that state but the fix should be simple:

- Right click the project and select "Open Module Settings"

[image]

- Make sure the SDK selected is a Java SDK, JDK 8 is assumed

[image]

Comment: Wow. Just like that? Your solution is spot on. BTW, I am using the latest plugin - 3.4.0. Previously, I selected other Non JDK SDK. I am using JDK 8 BTW. Thanks a lot....